# Обратная польская запись с проверкой корректности арифметического выражения

Tags: алгоритм

Я реализовал алгоритм перевода арифметического выражения из инфиксной в постфиксную запись и последующего вычисления, руководствуясь [данной статьей](https://habr.com/ru/post/489744/).

Но более-менее ёмко реализовать проверку корректности арифметического выражения у меня не получилось. Максимум - огромные костыльные связки if-else'ов с проверкой всевозможных вариантов.

Мне кажется, проверку можно реализовать более рационально, модифицировав алгоритм перевода в постфиксную запись. Но на ум ничего так и не пришло.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то скорректировать алгоритм под проверку? Или посоветуйте любой другой вариант решения данной проблемы.

*В выражении, из операторов, могут быть только* `+,-,*,/`*, а также скобки. Но при этом, выражение с избыточным количеством скобок (например :* `((1+2)*3)`*) будет считаться **некорректным**).*

***Числа все целые.***

**Алгоритм:**

1. Если входящий элемент число, то добавляем его в очередь (QUEUE).
2. Если входящий элемент оператор (+, -, *, /) то проверяем:

   - Если стек (STACK) пуст или содержит левую скобку в вершине (TOP), то
     добавляем (PUSH) входящий оператор в стек (STACK).
   - Если входящий оператор имеет более высокий приоритет чем вершина (TOP), поместите
     (PUSH) его в стек (STACK).
   - Если входящий оператор имеет более низкий или равный приоритет, чем вершине (TOP), выгружаем POP в очередь (QUEUE), пока не увидите оператор с меньшим приоритетом или левую скобку на вершине (TOP), затем добавьте (PUSH) входящий оператор в стек (STACK).
3. Если входящий элемент является левой скобкой, поместите (PUSH) его в стек (STACK).
4. Если входящий элемент является правой скобкой, выгружаем стек (POP) и добавляем его элементы в очередь (QUEUE), пока не увидите левую круглую скобку. Удалите найденную скобку из стека (STACK).
5. В конце выражения выгрузите стек (POP) в очередь (QUEUE)

Comment: Преобразуйте ОПЗ обратно. Если получилось что-то другое, выражение некорректно)

Comment: а ведь точно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из условия некорректности избыточных скобок, решением задачи будет обратное преобразование к инфиксной форме и сравнение с оригиналом.

Корректное выражение без избыточных скобок всегда даст то же самое выражение.

Обратное преобразование не отличается от вычисления выражения.
Только вместо вычисления операций нужно конкатенировать токены.